# How to remove the HTTP headers from a REST api call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, get

Hi i am trying to isolate the part of the response in the {}. It calls from the gemini public database and i am trying to get only the part in the curly braces to save it as a string in a database.

```
const gemini = async() =>{
    var burl = 'https://api.sandbox.gemini.com'
    var query = '/v1/pubticker/'+'ethusd'
    var url = burl + query
    var smth = fetch(url)
    delete smth.vary
    return smth

}

export default gemini
```

Here is the response i get

```
status: 200 OK
    content-length: 133
    content-type: application/json
    date: Mon, 08 Nov 2021 18:03:09 GMT
    server: nginx
    vary: Origin

{"bid":"4786.52","ask":"4787.78","volume":{"ETH":"8232.886562","USD":"38693689.50955448","timestamp":1636394400000},"last":"4786.83"}
```

This is what i want to isolate

`{"ETH":"8232.886562","USD":"38693689.50955448","timestamp":1636394400000},"last":"4786.83"}`

Comment: Step one is learning about `await`, and the `json()` function that you get from the result of `fetch()`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to "remove the headers".  Just get the JSON response and use the data you need from that response.  Your `gemini` function returns a `Promise` from a `fetch` call.  You'd use that `Promise` [like any other `fetch` call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).  For example:

```
let response = await gemini();
let result = await response.json();
```

Then `result` contains the object specified by the JSON data.  From the description in the question it sounds like you specifically want the `volume` and `last` properties on that object.